# Hair dynamics stops working after particle edit

Tags: particles, physics

Hair defaults to sticking straight out, and the dynamics moves it from there. I'd like to comb it to something more reasonable so the dynamics don't have to do as much work. The problem is that once I change something, the dynamics stop working entirely. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Hair dynamics are supposed to work with edited particles (just tested this). It could be you're still in particle edit mode, then go to object mode.

Comment: That seems to be my problem. Thanks. Want to repost that as an answer so I can mark it as one?

Comment: Sure, something nicer. This could help people with the same problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hair dynamics can use edited particules, something is stopping the normal process.

As you edited the particles, you're probably in particle edit mode.

[image]

This mode allows you to edit your particles but does not allow simulation
Go to object mode to start your sim.

[image]

Your simulation should be playing correctly with edited particles.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something I figured out after trying several times is that the dynamics get stuck in some strands because maybe some hairs are too close or in certain position than make it bug in some way.

What I did to bring back the collisions and dynamics without losing all the grooming an start a new one was just comb and groom the hair with Smooth and comb and all get back to work again.

[Also there is an amazing free plugin that give an option to apply the dynamics to the comb, like the cloth simulations.](https://app.gumroad.com/d/9d39d1c26702ebdf5b94a7f717232234?_ga=2.17620671.783777491.1649641335-1888479412.1597123033)